# Controlling component from backing bean

Tags: jsf, richfaces, components, javabeans

I want to 'update' a component with a new component in the bean.

**XHTML**

```
<composite:interface>
  <composite:attribute name="rootKey"   required="true" />
  <composite:attribute name="id"        required="true" />
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>

<rich:panel id="#{cc.attrs.id}" binding="#{myBean.customPanel}"/>

<a4j:jsFunction name="createPanels"
  action="#{myBean.createPanels}"
  render="#{cc.attrs.id}">
  <a4j:param name="rootId" assignTo="#{myBean.rootId}"/>
  <a4j:param name="rootKey" assignTo="#{myBean.rootKey}"/>
</a4j:jsFunction>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    createPanels('#{cc.attrs.id}','#{cc.attrs.rootKey}');
  });
/*]]>  */
</script>
</composite:implementation>
</ui:composition>
```

**Bean**

```
private UIPanel rootPanel;

public void setCustomPanel(UIPanel panel) {
  rootPanel = panel;
}

public UIPanel getCustomPanel() {
  return rootPanel;
}

public void createPanels() {
  //try #1 : Adding new panels as children
  rootPanel.getChildren().add((UIPanel)createPanels(rootId,rootKey));
  //try #2 : A new Panel component 
  rootPanel = (UIPanel)createPanels(rootId,rootKey); 
  ...
  rootPanel.setId(rootId); // this ID is the same as the 'placeholder' panelId 
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add(rootPanel.getId()); // the rerender should also already be done in the XHTML js function.
}
```

With the debugger i see the rootPanel changes into the new panel component, but not in the view. 
What do i miss?

What i try in short: Generating dynamically components as children for the panel component in the xhtml view. The generation needs the 'rootKey' param for generating the right set.

**Using:**

- JSF Mojarra 2.1.19
- Richfaces

Comment: Have you checked what response is coming from the server? (You can put a4j:log on your page to see it).

Comment: hmm, no i haven't checked the response. I'm unfamiliar with the a4j:log on the page. Ill check that log functionality (for future problems most likely very usefull)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to rerender te parent, not the actual component. 
Also adding the new element children as children to the bound component.

**XHTML** : Added a h:panelgroup around the place holder.

```
<h:panelGroup id="#{cc.attrs.id}_parent">
  <rich:panel id="#{cc.attrs.id}" binding="#{myBean.panel}"/> 
</h:panelGroup>

<a4j:jsFunction name="createPanels"
  action="#{myBean.createPanels}"
  render="#{cc.attrs.id}_parent">
  <a4j:param name="rootId" assignTo="#{myBean.rootId}"/>
  <a4j:param name="rootKey" assignTo="#{myBean.rootKey}"/>
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

**BEAN** : try #1 was the right one.

```
public void createPanels() {
  UIPanel newPanel = (UIPanel)createPanels(rootId,RootKey);
  if(newPanel.getChildCount() >= 1){
    rootPanel.getChildren().addAll(newPanel.getChildren());
    rootPanel.setStyleClass(newPanel.getStyleClass());
    rootPanel.setHeader(newPanel.getHeader());
  }
}
```